# How to use webservices with https in python

Tags: python, web-services

I have used below python code for web services but here my site url is include https. so if i use http then it gives "Method Not Found" error at the time web services runing and if i use https then this code is not working.

Anyone let me know how to resolve this issue with https.

```
import urllib
uid = username
pwd = psw   
params = urllib.urlencode({
    'uid': uid,
    'pwd': pwd,
data = urllib.urlopen(url, params).read()
print data
```

Or tell me any other method we can use web services.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Have you tried `urllib2`? http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html

Comment: If i use urllib2 then urlencode will not work, it gives me error and if i pass these parameter simply then it gives error.

Comment: Then why don't you use `urlencode` from `urllib` and `urlopen` from `urllib2`? Or you could have a look on http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

filmor have right. Try to use requests. An example of function :

```
def http_get(url, user=None, password=None, proxies=None, valid_response_status[httplib.OK], **kwargs):
"""
Performs a http get over an url
@param url: the url to perfom get against
@type url: str
@param user: user if authentication required
@type user: str
@param password: password if authentication required
@type password: str
@param proxies: proxies if required
@type proxies: dict
@param valid_response_status: http response status code considered as valid
@type valid_response_status: list of int
@raise exception: if the response status code is not in valid_response_status list
"""
auth = HTTPBasicAuth(username=user, password=password)
kwargs['proxies'] = proxies
kwargs['auth'] = auth
try:
    LOGGER.debug("Performing http get over : %s" % url)
    _request = requests.get(url, **kwargs)
    if _request.status_code not in valid_response_status:
        http_error_msg = '%s Error: %s' % (_request.status_code, _request.reason)
        http_error = HTTPError(http_error_msg)
        http_error.response = _request
        raise http_error
    return _request.content
except:
    LOGGER.error("Error while performing http get over : %s" % url)
    raise
```